# Como crear de forma multiple con smarter_csv para una API - Ruby on Rails

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, ruby

He buscado en internet si es igual crear masivamente con una API y la gema `smarter_csv`, pero no he conseguido nada todavía.

La tabla donde quiero insertar es la siguiente:

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "sku"
    t.string "origin_country"
    t.string "hs_code"
    t.integer "weight"
    t.string "value"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "seller_id"
    t.string "width"
    t.string "length"
    t.string "height"
    t.index ["seller_id"], name: "index_products_on_seller_id"
  end
```

Y para crear, el controller es el siguiente:

```
  def create
    seller_id = @current_user.sellers.first.id
    @product = Product.new(product_params.merge(seller_id: seller_id))
    if @product.save
      api_response({}, 'SUCCESS', ['Product created'])
    else
      api_response({}, 'ERROR', [@product.errors], 422)
    end
  end
```

Y la ruta, creo que debería ser la siguiente:

```
post '/product/upload', to: 'products#upload'
```

Comment: No sé si entiendo la pregunta. La acción `create` que tienes es para crear un sólo registro. Por otro lado hablas de un CSV con muchas entradas, y una ruta `upload`. ¿Entiendo que estás preguntando cómo crear la acción `upload` para crear registros para todas las entradas del CSV?

Comment: Por otro lado, hablas de una API: ¿entiendo que tienes resuelto ya el lado del cliente? Esto es: puedes enviar archivos por HTTP ya, y lo que necesitas es saber cómo tratarlos en el lado del servidor (la aplicación Rails). ¿Estoy en lo correcto?